# Error: Cannot find specified path for mongodb /data/db/testReplSet-0 when replicaSet.startSet()

Tags: mongodb, testing, local, replicaset

Trying to get the test setup locally for mongodb replication.
Steps I followed are:

```
$ mongo --nodb
> replicaSet = new ReplSetTest({"nodes" : 3})
> // starts three mongod processes
> replicaSet.startSet()
```

The third step is throwing errors. I already have a existing mongo db server running at port 27017 and data of that is stored at different folder in as specified in mongod.cfg

Im trying to create a test replica set on mongod instances on different ports .  The steps shown in below image show that 3 ports where selected for replication. Also I have made sure that we have a directory

```
/data/db
```

in

```
{mongodbinstallation folder}\bin\
```

Still I get the error for path not found.

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the db/path in the wrong place.  It's looking for top level /data/db and you say you created it in the bin directory of where mongodb is installed.

Since this looks like windows, create c:\data\db and then rerun this.